# How to filter data in a table based on the dropdown selection (Angular 8)?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, data-binding, dropdown

I have a table that is getting the data from an API. I'm trying to filter the data in the table when the user selects from the dropdown. Is this the best approach? The dropdown and table both disappear once i change the option from the dropdown. I also attached pictures below of what happens before and after user selects an option. Is there another, more efficient way?

projects.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css']
})

export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  public projects: vwMPLanding[];
  public cacheProjects: vwMPLanding[];



  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    let apiUrl = baseUrl + "api/majorprojects";
    console.log('[apiUrl]', apiUrl);
    http.get<vwMPLanding[]>(apiUrl).subscribe(result => {
      this.projects = result;
      this.cacheProjects = result;
      console.log(this.projects);

    }, error => console.error(error));

  }
  filterProjects(filterVal: any) {
    if (filterVal == "0")
      this.projects = this.cacheProjects;
    else
      this.projects = this.cacheProjects.filter((item) => (item.State) == filterVal);
  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }

}


interface vwMPLanding {
  ProjectId: number;
  legacyId: number;
  ProjectName: string;
  ProjectDesc: string;
  Status: string;
  Location: string;
  State: string;
  Abbrv: string;
}
```

projects.component.html

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="test">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="18%">
              <select (change)="filterProjects($event.target.value)">
                 <option value="0">All States</option>
                 <option *ngFor="let project of projects | distinct: 'state'" [value]="project.state">
                    {{project.abbrv + '-' + project.state }}
                 </option>
              </select>
          </th>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <th width="20%">Location</th>
          <th width="10%">Status</th>
          <th width="15%">Cost (in $M)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let project of projects; index as i">
             <td>{{ project.abbrv + '-' + project.state }}</td>
             <td>{{ project.projectName }}</td>
             <td>{{ project.location }}</td>
             <td>{{ project.status }}</td>
             <td>{{ project.cost }}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>

 </div>
```

[Before user selects option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zEz4.png)
[After user selects option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2o9Q.png)

Comment: You could create a `@Pipe` for this.

Comment: Have you considered using the table component from Angular Material? Also, PrimeNg has some excellent preexisting table components.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview
https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table